# Disallow all delete/update/insert using JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

In one of my applications I am providing the users the ability to issue direct SQL queries against a database.  They type the SQL text into a text box, then I run it exactly as is using JDBC.

Obviously I trust these users very much.  But I would like to limit them programatically to issuing only SELECT statements.  They should never DELETE/UPDATE/INSERT.  I thought maybe JDBC itself could help me here.  I found the executeQuery() method in the java.sql.Statement class.  But that method allows me to call DELETE (and maybe UPDATE and INSERT too).  It does throw an Exception because no ResultSet is returned, but only after deleting the records.

So, I ask here, is there any way in JDBC to make sure that a SQL statement is only performed if it is a query?  Or do I have to parse the statement myself and make sure it complies with my wishes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you connect to the DBMS with a user that lacks the DELETE / UPDATE and INSERT permissions.

Comment: Yes, probably a more elegant solution.  Thanks.